# how to locate pseudo elements on angular page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

how can I locate pseduo element (::after) ? I need to perform some mouse actions on that element.

`<th class = 'somename'> ::before "th label" ::after </th>`

the after element contains the splitter for th, I need to locate that element and perform mousedown and mousemove actions on it

Comment: Just select appropriate `<th>`. Pseudo element is not a part of `HTML` `DOM`, so you cannot locate it